# TSC error when compiling through Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I have a Node / TypeScript application which I'm trying to run from Docker.

`yarn tsc` works fine locally, but does not work in the context of the Dockerfile. I think the issue is regarding which directory the command is being run from with the Dockerfile, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

How can I make sure `tsc` can see the `tsconfig.json` file?

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn

# Copy source files.
COPY . .

# Run tsc.
RUN yarn prepare

# Run app.
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

#### package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "prepare": "yarn tsc",
    "tsc": "tsc -p .",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly server.ts",
    "start": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js ./build/server.js",
  },
```

#### Error output

```
docker build --tag app ./
Sending build context to Docker daemon  114.1MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:10
 ---> e05cbde47b8f
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> faaea91b16ae
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> 64310f50355d
Step 4/7 : RUN yarn
 ---> Running in be8aed305980
yarn install v1.16.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
$ yarn tsc
yarn run v1.16.0
$ tsc -p ./
error TS5057: Cannot find a tsconfig.json file at the specified directory: './'.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As David said,

> Just running yarn is equivalent to yarn install, which runs a "prepare" script.

You could change your script to copy the application code to the given directory before running yarn command, if you do not need for yarn command to run first.

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy source files.
COPY . .
RUN yarn

# Run app.
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Comment: (The reason to just `COPY package.json` first is so that, the second time you `docker build`, Docker layer caching knows that it can skip downloading all the packages in the `yarn install` step.  In this form since probably something in your source tree has changed somewhere, Docker doesn't know that and will repeat the download every time.)

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at your `docker build` output, you'll notice that the last `Dockerfile` instruction that gets run is the

```
Step 4/7 : RUN yarn
```

In particular, [yarn treats a couple of script names as special](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/package-json#toc-scripts).  Just running `yarn` is [equivalent](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/#toc-default-command) to `yarn install`, which runs a "prepare" script.  In your case the "prepare" script runs `tsc`; but, this is happening during the "install dependencies" phase of the `Dockerfile`, and your application code isn't there yet.

You can work around this by using [yarn's `--ignore-scripts` option](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-ignore-scripts).  A number of other options make sense here in the context of building a Docker image.  (You could use a multi-stage build to build a final image with only `--production` dependencies and not the `tsc` compiler or other build-time tools, for example.)

```sh
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --ignore-scripts --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive

COPY . .
RUN yarn prepare

CMD ["node", "./build/server.js"]
```